# Why is scrollbar of JScrollPane present from the start of the application?

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel, jscrollpane, vertical-scroll

I am trying to make a graphical interface in Java with Netbeans. I use a *JFrame Form*. Inside it, a *JScrollPane* contains a *JPanel*. Within the *JScrollPane*, assigned the property *verticalScrollBarPolicy* the value *"AS_NEEDED"* in order to scroll only if the content is too large.

But my problem is that the vertical scrollbar is present from the start of the application. How to solve it?

I put the *setLayout* method on my *JPanel* in my constructor (which was before in my *jMenuItem1ActionPerformed* method), and it seems to work.

However, i have another small problem. when I open few files, a gap that is much too big separates them (which is not the case when there are many files).

Below, the visual IHM, the properties of *JPanel* and *JScrollPane* and the code produced.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

```
public class Items_IHM extends javax.swing.JFrame {

JCheckBox checkBox;
List<JCheckBox> listOfCheckBox = new ArrayList<>();
File[] allFiles;
File folder;

/**
 * Creates new form Items_IHM
 */
public Items_IHM() {
    initComponents();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    srollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    buttonExecute = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    srollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    srollPane.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 400));
    srollPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 300));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 339, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 477, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    srollPane.setViewportView(panel);

    buttonExecute.setText("Execute");
    buttonExecute.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonExecuteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jMenu1.setText("Fichier");

    jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_O, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem1.setText("Ouvrir");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Q, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem2.setText("Quitter");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Editer");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(buttonExecute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(srollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 341, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(srollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 479, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(buttonExecute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed
    Preferences preferences = Preferences.userRoot();
    String path = preferences.get("DEFAULT_PATH", "");
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(path));
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //  allNameFilesTextArea.setText("");
        folder = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(folder);
        preferences.put("DEFAULT_PATH", folder.getAbsolutePath());
        allFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
            }
        });
        listOfCheckBox.clear();
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            checkBox = new JCheckBox(allFiles[i].getName());
            listOfCheckBox.add(checkBox);
            panel.add(checkBox);
        }
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed

private void buttonExecuteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_buttonExecuteActionPerformed
    Items_Application itemsApp;
    try {
        if (listOfCheckBox.size() > 0) {
            itemsApp = new Items_Application(folder.getPath());
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfCheckBox.size(); i++) {
                if (listOfCheckBox.get(i).isSelected()) {
                    itemsApp.loadInItem(allFiles[i].getPath());
                }
            }
            itemsApp.buildListOfItemsWithSamePartNb();
            itemsApp.buildListOfItemsWithSameThalesNb();
            itemsApp.writeOutItems(folder.getPath());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_buttonExecuteActionPerformed

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem2ActionPerformed
    System.exit(0);
}//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem2ActionPerformed

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Items_IHM.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Items_IHM.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Items_IHM.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Items_IHM.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Items_IHM().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Anyone has an idea?